# Rails 5: When setting the default value of a select, the corresponding jquery function returns the wrong value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5

I am updating my rails app at the moment. Since I reached rails 5 I found an unexpected behaviour in relation to setting the default value.

At the moment I am on

- ruby 2.2.2
- rails 5.0.7.2
- jquery-rails '~> 4.4'
- jquery-ui-rails '>= 6.0.1'

The app is using jquery3

I have the following options:

```
<select name="cat_id" id="cat_id" title="Object" class="select outtaHere">
   <option value="-1">option1</option>
   <option value="1">option2</option>
   <option value="2">option3</option>
</select>
```

I use the following function to build my select tag:

```
def q_select_tag(model, name, model_class, title = nil)
    options_list = model_class.all.collect{ |r| [r[ApplicationHelper::description_column], r.id] } #[["option1", -1], ["option2", 1], ["option3", 2]]
    defaultOption = 1
    select_tag name, options_for_select(options_list, defaultOption), :title => title, :class => 'select'  
end
```

In my ERB I call it like this:

```
 <%= q_select_tag q, :cat_id, category, label %>
```

I also have a jquery function in this erb to modify my form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('select#cat_id').change( function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  })});
jQuery('select#cat_id').change();
</script>
```

When I run it appears to work fine, but when I switch between the default option option2 (value: 1) and option1 (value: -1) my jquery function returns always -1. This does not happen when I switch between option1 and option3 or option2 and option3.

Here a the console of my firefox switcheing between option2 and option1 back and force and switching between option 2 to option 3 after that:
[image: console log firefox]

I tried to find this problem online, but was not successful with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The HTML + JS appears to work fine on their own for me here. I wasn't able to reproduce the error using the `q_select_tag` method. Maybe take a look in the direction of turbolinks? That's been known to cause some odd behavior with inline JS.

Comment: Thank you scilence, will have a look at tubolinks...

Comment: Hi scilence, I checked the app but I am not using turbolinks within the app...

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you then. There's something going on in your setup. Like I said, the code you posted works fine in the rails application I pasted it into.

Comment: Thanks I will try to upgrade to a higher version of rails... Lets see what I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Reference:
I could fix the problem after updating to rails 5.1.7 and ruby 2.3.0 the problem was solved.